# Conteo de registro hasta un caracter especial SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo el siguiente script sencillo:

```
SELECT '24/7/2021','2021/07/28'
```

Y quiero que me cuenta la cantidad de dígitos que hay antes del primer "/". El resultado que espero es:

```
'24/7/2021','2021/07/28'
   2       ,  4
```

o sea en la primera fecha hay 2 dígitos antes del primer /, y en la segunda fecha hay 4 dígitos antes del primer /.

Comment: Hola, podrías decir si las respuestas dadas te resultaron útiles, y marcar como aceptada la que mejor te haya parecido, y si lo consideras dar un voto positivo también, gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola puedes usar [PATINDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

```
SELECT PATINDEX('%/%', '2021/07/28') - 1  -- 4
SELECT PATINDEX('%/%', '24/7/2021') - 1   -- 2
```

Comment: Es más eficiente el CHARINDEX cuando es un caracter específico.

Answer (score 2):

Ampliando la respuesta de **@JorgeLuis**, también puedes usar la **función CHARINDEX**:

```
SELECT CHARINDEX('/', '2021/07/28') - 1
SELECT CHARINDEX('/', '24/7/2021') - 1
```

Ambas funciones arrojan el mismo resultado, la diferencia está en que la **función PATINDEX** permite usar caracteres comodines para hacer **búsquedas de patrones**; por otra parte la **función CHARINDEX** puede aceptar un tercer argumento que indica a partir de que posición comenzar la búsqueda dentro de la cadena.